# CSS Clip Path hides elements

Tags: css

I'm using `clip-path` for a gradient at the top of a page on my site. Ideally the two angles would meet up and there would be no issues.

I've positioned the top so that they touch and nothing should be in the angled content. I initially used `top: -120px;` but changed it to `margin-top: -120px;` It looks fine and the positioning could stay if this is the best approach.

The issue is that the content gets stuck underneath like this;

```css
.site-hero-colour {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFFFFF, #000000);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-hero-colour {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFFFFF, #000000);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 90%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
}

.site-hero-content {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 160px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -120px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-hero-content {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 160px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 10%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="site-hero-colour"></div>
<div class="site-hero-content">
   <h1>This gets cut off. It should sit on top of the white space or be positoned to match up.</h1>
</div>
```

My thought is to do something like this instead

```css
.site-hero-colour {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    max-height: 600px;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFFFFF, #000000);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-hero-colour {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFFFFF, #000000);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 90%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
}

.site-hero-content {
    min-width: 100%;
    background: pink;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -120px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-hero-content {
    min-width: 100%;
    background: pink;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 10%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
}

.new {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-hero-colour"></div>
<div class="site-hero-content"></div>
<div class="new"> <h1>This gets cut off. It should sit on top of the white space or be positoned to match up.</h1></div>
```

This way the content sits below once the height has been removed for that element. I'm wondering if there's a better approach to take than this one for marrying them up without using `top` or just having an empty DIV here. I'm mainly looking for opinions or better approaches because I've found something that sort of works. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like a square split into two polygon?

try calc clip-path property like below.

```css
.site-hero-colour {
      min-width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      min-height: 600px;
      max-height: 600px;
      background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFFFFF, #000000);
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 calc(100% - 100px));
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      position: relative;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .site-hero-colour {
        min-width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        min-height: 400px;
        max-height: 400px;
        background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #FFFFFF, #000000);
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 90%);
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
      }
    }

    .site-hero-content {
      min-width: 100%;
      background: pink;
      /* clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 20%, 100% 100%, 0 100%); */
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100px, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
      position: relative;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      padding-top: 100px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="site-hero-colour"></div>
  <div class="site-hero-content">
    <h1>This gets cut off. It should sit on top of the white space or be positoned to match up.</h1>
  </div>
```